# Verify excel or word is really running or not (has a open window) in the system

Tags: winapi, vba, excel, process

When we look at Windows Task Manager Process sometimes we see excel.exe or winword.exe is running, but there are no excel or word windows open in the system. But it's running in the memory.
How do I find out for a excel.exe or winword.exe which is in task manager process has an open window or not?
These excel.exe or winword.exe is created by a different application which is not closing it correctly. I cannot fix that application, but I need to close this process.

Is there a way to find out whether there's a window/application is really open in the system?

I can check and kill the process with the following code,but it fails when the excel file is opened from a website where there's no Window Title in Excel.

```
Process[] procs;
try {
       procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
       foreach (Process curprocess in procs) 
       {
         if (!curprocess.HasExited && string.IsNullOrEmpty(curprocess.MainWindowTitle))
         {
           curprocess.Kill(); }
         }
      }
      catch (Exception ex) {
                WriteLog(ex.ToString());
     }
```

Any suggestions to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try making it quit on its own. I think the following methods should be available to you.

```
curprocess.Application.Quit();}
```

Good luck, LC

Comment: I'm able to kill the application, but I want to kill/quit only application with no window is open. Ex. execl.exe is running in task process but I want to kill only orphan excel process which doesn't have a window.